# How to run activex control in windows 8

Tags: windows, activex, internet-explorer-10

I have an intranet application that uses activex. It runs fine in Windows 7 but not in Windows 8. I've used caspol to grant full trust, I've set IE 10 to allow downloading and running of activex controls.

I've even tried to run it in Chrome with an activex addon.

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: This sounds like a job for serverfault.com.

Comment: I'll try over there, thanks.